# can't iterate through element not with range() nor with len()

Tags: python, python-3.x

i tried to use for loop to iterate through the length of input (string) but when i tried using len() OR range() they gave me error saying that the type is wrong.

this code is a start of Cows and Bulls game.
tried changing object type to list.
switched between sublime text and idle.
i checked the type of the input using the type() method

```
import random
target = [random.randint(0, 9) for i in range(4)]
turns = 0
all_cows = False
while not all_cows:
    guess = input('Cows and Bulls!\nguess 4 numbers: ')
    turns += 1
        #tried doing range(guess) does not work! *type of guess is string
        #len(guess) - error cant iterate through int
        #range(guess) error cannot be interpreted as an integer
    for item in len(guess):
        if guess[item] == target[item]:
            print('cow')
        elif guess[item] in target:
            print('bull')`
```

Program output:

```
Cows and Bulls!
guess 4 numbers: 1111
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Computers\Programming\Python\Codes\Exercises\17.py", line 8, in <module>
    for item in len(guess):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable




Cows and Bulls!
guess 4 numbers: 1111
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Computers\Programming\Python\Codes\Exercises\17.py", line 8, in <module>
    for item in range(guess):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to combine `range()` and `len()`. By using

```
for index in range(len(guess)):
    # your code here
```

you can iterate over the length of the guess.

You can also directly iterate over `guess`, but since you also need the index of each character, you need to use `enumerate()`. This will return two values for each character, the first is the index, the second is the character itself. So you would do:

```
for index, c in enumerate(guess):
    # your code here with index as the index and c as the character
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `guess` acquired by `input` is of type string (as are inputs). Then, the type of `len(guess)` is obviously int. You can't iterate over an int as it is not a sequence. You have a few options to overcome this problem:

1. iterate over the indices using [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range):

```py
for i in range(len(guess)):
    if int(guess[i]) == target[i]:
```

2. you could use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```py
for i, c in enumerate(guess):
    if int(c) == target[i]:
```

3. Turn your input from the user to a list of [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)s:

```py
guess = input('Cows and Bulls!\nguess 4 numbers: ')
guesses = [int(c) for c in guess]

for i in range(len(guess)):
    if guess[i] == target[i]:
```

<sub>could also be done using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):  `guesses = list(map(int, guess))`</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
could you please elaborate on the enumerate method?
i tried converting the string to a list (obviously the same err occurred ( which is solver by using range(len()) ) so what is the point in converting the string to a list in that case?

Comment: @NanashiSenpai I have updated my answer with links. In short, enumerate returns a tuple, consisting of (index, item) from the list. So it basically saves you the `guess[i]`. As to the list is just a matter of prespective. You already have your data ready from the start and that saves you the `int(...)`

Comment: so i = index and c = item?
how does the iteration works then? it iterates index and item in what?

Comment: just as by doing `for x in l:` you get each element in `l` in its turn, here you get the element in `c` **and** its index in `i`. So you don't need to loop on indices and then do `guess[i]`, because you already have it for free... Have a look in the link

Answer (score 0):

`input()` Function in python3 takes eac value as `str` 
So you need to convert it into `int` by using `int()` Function 
Check with following Code :

```
import random
target = [random.randint(0, 9) for i in range(4)]
turns = 0
all_cows = False
while not all_cows:
    guess = input('Cows and Bulls!\nguess 4 numbers: ')
    turns += 1
    #Iterate String  Directly
    for item in guess:
    #Convert Substring into int for using as Indices
        if guess[int(item)] == target[int(item)]:
            print('cow')
        elif guess[int(item)] in target:
            print('bull')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for helping my out on that case.
seems like the problem is in me not understanding len() right, i forgot it returns the length as int and got confused when the err said object type int.

solution 1: using range(len(guess)) to iterate through through the length of the string.

solution 2: iterating through the string directly - wasn't what i searched for since i wanted to use the 'item' to index the string.

solution 3: using enumerate(guess) which i never heard of (so if someone is bored and want to explain it ill accept the explanation gratefully!
edit: got my answer.